# How to create Array | List in Azure Pipelines (.yml) Dynamically

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I came across a scenario, where I need to create an Array variable or a list. The values which I am expecting are of type **String**

I am getting those individual values inside the loop (**Variable1** in the below code). I want to set those values as a variable (**arrayVariable** in the below code)  so that I can use those values in different tasks or templates.

```
variables:
  - name: arrayVariable
    value:

steps:

- powershell: |
      ## Some Other Conditional Code 
      For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
      {
         $Variable1=$temp[$i]
         echo "this is $Variable1 value" ## Here I can have multiple values on the basis of loop
         
         ## This value i want to keep in Array or in List to reffer it another task/templates.
         
         Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=arrayVariable]$Variable1"
         echo "Variable's value in loop  $Variable1"
      }
  displayName: 'Powershell Task'
```

Please let me know if the creation of the list or array is possible at runtime.

Any Help | Guidance will be appreciable.

Comment: Hi Eddie, Maybe you could save the variable in the json file and then refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59965101/azure-pipelines-add-new-element-in-json-array-vsts-pipelines-appsettings-json) to add new variables.

Comment: This is not quite possible out of the box (unfortunately), but there is a workaround check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483194/pass-array-of-files-into-the-parameter-of-awscli1-task/67498247#67498247

Comment: @VitoLiu : Thanks I have checked that But, It doesn't work in my case

Comment: @Bruno : Thanks for the clarification. on line `echo "Variable's value in loop  $Variable1"` I am getting the required value. I just want to copy that in the array or in list. If its possible

Comment: As I mentioned, variables in Azure Pipelines don't support Arrays or lists, therefore what you wanna do it's just not possible, but you can workaround it.

Answer (score 0):

Azure pipeline variables are just strings. However you could store an array or some json in a string and serialise it back out. That will work if you just want to use the variable to pass into more PowerShell later on in the pipeline.

Try something like this:

```
$Variable1 = ""
## Some Other Conditional Code 
  For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
  {
     $Variable1 = $Variable1, $temp[$i] -join " "
     echo "this is $Variable1 value" ## Here I can have multiple values on the basis of loop
     
     ## This value i want to keep in Array or in List to reffer it another task/templates.
     
     Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=arrayVariable]$Variable1"
     echo "Variable's value in loop  $Variable1"
  }
```

If you pass that back into later PowerShell as a variable and split it then you'll have something you can loop over.

```
$arrayVariable = $(arrayVariable) -split
```